# Why won't Task Scheduler run my Python Script

Tags: python-3.x, excel, pandas, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to run the python script using task scheduler, I have written a batch file;

```
"C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\python.exe" "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python_Code\Python3.6\Web_Scraping\Firmware_Upgrade\Set_Check_Upgrade_v7.py"
```

Which works with a simple Hello World type example.

When I try and run my actual code I get the error message below;

```
C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\python.exe" "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python_Code\Python3.6\Web_Scraping\Firmware_Upgrade\Set_Check_Upgrade_v7.py"

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53073/devtools/browser/18cef93b-eaa4-4e14-9439-6f0b66b60727
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Documents\Python_Code\Python3.6\Web_Scraping\Firmware_Upgrade\Set_Check_Upgrade_v7.py", line 22, in <module>
    firmware_data = pd.read_excel(total_string)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 304, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 824, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 353, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "C:\Program Files\WinPython64\python-3.7.7.amd64\Lib\site-packages\xlrd\__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Upgrade_v5.22_01-08-2020.xlsx'
```

The python code I have used is

```
file_string = 'Upgrade_v5.22_01-08-2020'
total_string = file_string + '.xlsx'

firmware_data = pd.read_excel(total_string)
```

Which works when running in the Pycharms IDE but not using the Windows 10 Task Scheduler App.

The Excel file is in the same directory as the Python file.

I have tried creating the task with "Run with highest privileges" enabled but this makes no difference.

Comment: Check whether using the full path to the file in your script will do the job.

Comment: I've just checked on my Linux machine what the current working directory is when running the script from command line and from IDE: the results are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your script file directory to the *.xlsx* file name variable. `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mr/Mrs/Ms Eniac for your help I used the full file path and that has worked. Feel rather silly I didn't think of that but appears to be solved. Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help :) Mark the question as solved, please. So, others will be able see the solution at once.